# Proper use of a Lookup table and adaptations for NET

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, enums

I need to create a few lookup tables and I often see the following:

```
create table Languages
(
  Id int identity not null primary key (Id),      
  Code nvarchar (4) not null,
  Description nvarchar (120) not null,
);

create table Posts
(
  Id int identity not null primary key (Id),      
  LanguageId int not null,
  Title nvarchar (400) not null,
);

insert into Languages (Id, Code, Description) values (1, "en", "English");
```

This way I am localizing Posts with language id ...

IMHO, this is not the best scheme for Languages table because in a Lookup table the PK should be meaningful, right?

So instead I would use the following:

```
create table Languages
(
  Code nvarchar (4) not null primary key (Code),      
  Description nvarchar (120) not null,
);

create table Posts
(
  Id int identity not null primary key (Id),      
  LanguageCode nvarchar (4) not null,
  Title nvarchar (400) not null,
);

insert into Languages (Code, Description) values ("en", "English");
```

The NET applications usually use language code so this way I can get a Post in English without using a Join.

And with this approach I am also maintaining the database data integrity ...

This could be applied to Genders table with codes "M", "F", countries table, transaction types table (should I?), ...

However I think it is common to use int as PK in lookup tables because it is easier to map to ENUMS.

And know it is even possible to map to Flag Enums so have a Many to Many relationship in an ENUM.

That helps in NET code but in fact has limitations. A Languages table could never be mapped to a FLags Enum ...

... An flags enum can't have more than 64 items (Int64) because the keys must be a power of two.

**A SOLUTION**

I decided to find an approach that enforces database data integrity and still makes possible to use enums so I tried:

```
create table Languages
(
  Code nvarchar (4) not null primary key (Code),
  Key int not null,      
  Description nvarchar (120) not null,
);

create table Posts
(
  Id int identity not null primary key (Id),      
  LanguageCode nvarchar (4) not null,
  Title nvarchar (400) not null,
);

insert into Languages (Code, Key, Description) values ("en", 1, "English");
```

With this approach I have a meaningfully Language code, I avoid joins and I can create an enum by parsing the Key:

```
public enum LanguageEnum {
  [Code("en")
  English = 1
}
```

I can even preserve the code in an attribute. Or I can switch the code and description ...

What about Flag enums? Well, I will have not Flag enums but I can have List ...

And when using List I do not have the limitation of 64 items ...

To me all this makes sense but would I apply it to a Roles table, or a ProductsCategory table?

In my opinion I would apply only to tables that will rarely change over time ... So:

```
Languages, Countries, Genders, ... Any other example?
```

About the following I am not sure (They are intrinsic to the application):

```
PaymentsTypes, UserRoles
```

And to these I wouldn't apply (They can be managed by a CMS):

```
ProductsCategories, ProductsColors
```

What do you think about my approach for Lookup tables?

Comment: Why a vote for close? What is wrong with my question?

Comment: It's mostly because it's unclear what you're asking here (mainly because you're apparently talking to yourself rather than asking / answering your own question in SO's Q&A format). Hope that helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first way of doing it is correct, with an ID as a PK. (You can also set a unique index on the Code column.)

> 'PK should be meaningful, right?'

Nope. This not a requirement; I have never heard of it in many many years of DBMS work.

Bear in mind that most RDBMS' have optimisations for int keys and will look up and int PK faster than most other data types. That's one of the reason's why IDENTITY is used for so many PK's.

Comment: There is nothing wrong with using a natural key. For the case of a language I would argue that using the ANSI code for that language is a perfect primary key for a languages table. "en-us" is very clear where 1 (the identity value) does not provide any additional benefit. When you get into performance problems using character data as keys is when the width of the values varies greatly.

Comment: @SeanLange: True, yes. However the point of using an IDENTITY is that no changes need be made when something changes it's name. While it is very likely that a language code like 'en-us' or any of the 100's of other language codes will not change, there's still a finite chance (I'm in the Nitpicker's corner now!) My major point is that there is no requirement for the PK of a lookup table to be the lookup Code instead of an Id.

Comment: LOL. The discussion (argument) about natural vs surrogate keys has been going on forever. There is more likelihood that the planet will be obliterated by a meteor tomorrow than ANSI changing the values for language codes. My point is that you stated that using an identity is the right way to do it. Many times in a lookup table I would agree, but other times it just doesn't make sense to me. Do you use an identity for a States table? If so, how does assigning an essentially random number to a state help?

Comment: Do you have any links that support your claim that "most RDBMS' have optimisations for int keys and will look up and int PK faster than most other data types"?

Comment: :) For a States table, I do use random ints, yes! Eccentric, I know, but it makes for a consistent pattern... I did look for links for my optimasition claim, but the ones I checked were mostly throwaway remarks like mine. Even http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unique_key has [citation needed] next to Surrogate key, so I may need to do a bit of thinking about this. Live and learn!

Comment: hehe by no means am I saying that what you are doing with identity values is wrong or eccentric. In fact, many people just use an identity column as the primary key without giving it any thought. I will consider my job complete because I did at least help you think about it for a second. :)

Comment: Well, it seems I ended up with one of those discussions that have no solution ... lol. I understand that using an ID identity as primary key might be safer.